# when using the spring cloud data flow sftp source starter app file_name header is not found

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-integration-sftp

spring cloud dataflow sftp source starter app [states that file name should be in the headers](https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/sftp/blob/master/spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-sftp/README.adoc) (`mode=contents`). However, when I connect this source to a log sink, I see a few headers (like `Content-Type`) but not the `file_name` header. I want to use this header to upload the file to S3 with the same name.

spring server: `Spring Cloud Data Flow Local Server  (v1.2.3.RELEASE)`

my apps are all imported from [here](https://repo.spring.io/libs-release/org/springframework/cloud/stream/app/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor/Celsius.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream-app-descriptor-Celsius.RELEASE.kafka-10-apps-maven-repo-url.properties)

stream definition:
`stream create --definition "sftp --remote-dir=/incoming --username=myuser --password=mypwd --host=myftp.company.io --mode=contents --filename-pattern=preloaded_file_2017_ --allow-unknown-keys=true | log" --name test_sftp_log`

configuring the log application to `--expression=#root --level=debug` doesn't make any difference. Also, writing my own sink that tries to access the `file_name` header I get an error message that such header does not exist

logs snippets from the source and sink [are in this gist](https://gist.github.com/omerholz/aedb2245f3230eacc4e96a506e57fcfa)

Answer (score 1):

Please follow this link bellow, You need to code your own `Source` and populate such a header manually downstream already after `FileReadingMessageSource`. And only after that send the message with content and appropriate header to the target destination.
https://github.com/spring-cloud-stream-app-starters/file/issues/9